# Rewrite rule loses query parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, rewritecond, querystring

I have a webserver running apache2 with php7.

In my apache config, there is a redirect rule like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.*
RewriteRule .* %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This should perform a redirect form `http(s)://example.com/scpript?param1=x&param2=y` to `http(s)://www.example.com/scpript?param1=x&param2=y`

It basically works, with one exception: only the first get parameter gets passed to the rewitten url, so my client actually recieves `http(s)://www.example.com/scpript?param1=x` as redirection target.

I'm quite puzzled, how do I get the system to pass the full query along?

if also tried

```
RewriteRule .* %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

But that redirects me to `http(s)://www.example.com/scpript?param1=x&param1=x`. It looks like something omits the other parameters before the rewrite comes into action.

Comment: There would seem to be "something else" going on here. Since you appear to be behind a proxy server (and the `QUERY_STRING` server variable is modified) I suspect your proxy server is modifying the request and stripping this other parameter as it is passed through?